# Qt file manager with undo

Tags: linux, desktop-environment

I'm looking for a qt file manager with the following features (which should be a reasonable ask, but I've yet to find one):

- undo support
- tabs
- zero animations (this excludes all kde ones more or less)
- the ability to have a 'detailed view': file types, modification & creation dates

I'm using nemo for now which is gtk based but supports all of the above.

Comment: Just for clarification: You're looking for a) a "file manager with undo" (title), or b) a "desktop manager" (text of your question)? From the other details I think it's safe to assume "desktop manager" was a "typo" here, but … // As LXDE is moving QT, it might be worth checking with that (DE as well as its apps, here the file manager).

Comment: @Izzy Yes this was a typo, fixed now. I've used lxde before but it's file managers had no undo. A lot of the minimal ones don't which is a shame.

Comment: What kind of Undo are you missing there, for what actions? I'm a bit at a loss concerning this requirement. I doubt there is something like a "transactional FM" (where you first stack all your changes, and then "commit" them). Should it be a trashbin (undelete) – or do you even want to undo copy/rename actions? You probably can't undo "view" actions (if you've seen something, you cannot make it unseen by you ;)

Comment: @Izzy Just the edit actions: undelete (trashbin), move, copy, rename. Isn't always possible, say if I delete a file completely, or when somebody else changes something outside the FM :)

Comment: For Trashbins there are IMHO Linux applications available (or, IOW, you can establish that functionality on OS level). I'm not aware that anything like that exists for the other operations (move, copy, rename) – though it would be technically possible I'd say.